# Store information into Json file in java

Tags: java, json

I am using JSONObject library in order to store data in json file from my java code. I came across the following [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) about JSONObject. What I am trying to figure out is how the Json hierarchy could work. Basically I want to store in a json file all the X and Y mouse events and the correspondant timestamps. I have the following code:

```
Jobj = new JSONObject();
Jobj.put("user interactions", "Learning game applications"); 
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = event -> {
        event.getSceneX();
        event.getSceneY();
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        list.add(event.getSceneX());
        list.add(event.getSceneY());
        Jobj.put("Mouse Events", list);

    };
```

When I am trying to store this Json object into file I got just only one (X, Y, Time). How can I got all of them?

> {"Mouse Events":[2016-11-02 14:49:07.1,457.0,642.0],"user interactions":"Learning game applications"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the array in an object "Mouse Events". 
Every time you reach the line

```
Jobj.put("Mouse Events", list);
```

the previous entry is overwritten.
What you want is to have an **array** "Mouse events" and add new arrays to the array on every event.

Retrieve the value as a JSONArray, add() the new JSONArray to the array you retrieved, then store it again in Jobj.

Comment: I need to store (X, Y, time) every event tick. So isnt it that I want a 2d array?

Comment: It's an array of arrays. You add one array every time the event happens.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier for you to understand if you create an object per event with the keys "x", "y" and "timestamp" and add the object to the array "Mouse events" every time the event occurs.